# Applying KNN Clustering based on user id

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, knn

Dataset file : [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UuWMK1XH52mU4L6hoI1vhR8RVdF_fxgO/view?usp=sharing)

Hello Community , I need help regarding how to apply **KNN** clustering on this use case.

I have a dataset consisting `(27884 ROWS, 8933 Columns)`

Here's a little preview of a dataset

| user_iD | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 | b6 | b7 | b8 | b9 | b10 | b11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 10 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 0 | 5 |  | 6 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 4 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 7 |

Here the column userid represents: **STUDENTS**
and columns b1-b11: They represent Book Chapters and the sequence of each student that which chapter he/she studied first then second then third and so on.  the 0 entry tells that the student did not study that particular chapter.

This is just a small preview of a big dataset.
There are a total of **27884** users and **8932** Chapters stated as (b1--b8932)

I need to find a similar pattern and thus need to apply `KNN` clustering, how do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "find a similar pattern"? KNN is a classifier algorithm, which means you need to provide labels for the training.  I think you want an unsupervised algorithm, but with 8932 features, you are going to run into the curse of dimensionality.

Comment: I assume you're not talking about a single book with 8932 chapters, but rather many different books with a combined 8932 chapters. Perhaps a way around the curse of dimensionality would be to do the clustering for individual books separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have class labels in your data, I'm guessing [you may want K-Means](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/how-is-the-k-nearest-neighbor-algorithm-different-from-k-means-clustering/#:%7E:text=KNN%20represents%20a%20supervised%20classification,into%20k%20number%20of%20clusters.) to cluster your data, rather than KNN. Here's a simple K-Means example. If for some reason, you actually do want KNN for classification, please elaborate on classification labels and I will try to assist.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_feather('Bundles.ftr')

# It's common to split your data into train and test groups See  
# https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html for more info.
df_train = df.head(500)

# put all of the feature columns into a list of lists
x_list = []
for idx, row in df_train.iterrows():
    x_list.append(row.iloc[1:].tolist())
# put our feature lists into np arrray
X = np.array(x_list)
# fit the data, tweak params as needed
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10, random_state=0).fit(X)

# assign cluster labels to df
df_train['labels'] = kmeans.labels_
```

Next let's look at how many values are in each cluster.

```
df_train['labels'].value_counts()
```

From this cluster distribution, we can see that the data are unbalanced.

```
1    415
5     57
7      9
3      5
0      4
6      3
2      3
9      2
8      1
4      1
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```

If you want to predict which cluster other rows might belong to. This code tells us that the row at index 999 is predicted to belong in cluster 1.

```
kmeans.predict([df.iloc[999:1000, 1:].values.flatten().tolist()])
```